# Which is more eligible for termination? A service process or a service + stopped activity process?

Tags: android

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle), both should have the same priority:

> Android ranks a process at the highest level it can, based upon the importance of the components currently active in the process.
>
> Using a service guarantees that the operation will have at least "service process" priority, regardless of what happens to the activity.

Is this really the case? Isn't memory usage a factor? If the services in both processes consume the same amount of memory while the killed activity consumes alot more (not garbage collected yet or because of leaks), would that make its process more eligible for termination?

Context:
My app consists of a service and an activity. It's important (for the user) that the service remains running even when the activity is not so to decrease the probability that it will be terminated I decided to assign each a separate process. The justification for this so far is possible unhandled exceptions in the activity that can bring down the whole process. I want to know if I should consider termination policies as another reason.

*Foreground service is not an option.
*The service is sticky (I just want to decrease downtime).

P.S., English is not my first language. Feel free to rephrase my question and correct any technical or grammar mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

For your context you can make the service Sticky which will restart it upon destroyed.

Starting service in different process is not the solution, if you need it to run continuously. I am guessing you did it because your service got destroyed when Activity crashed. This happens because process is terminated when activity crashes or is force closed. Also, make sure your service is not bounded to Activitie's lifecycle

Comment: It's already sticky. I just want to increase the probability that its hosting process won't be terminated (i.e., reduce downtime). And the process has not crashed, I'm just considering all the possibilities.